# Chosen.js Multiple select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Is there a way to set up chosen on a multiple select box so that when items are selected just the option values are shown instead of the option name by default.

```
<select multiple>
<option value="A">America</option>
<option value="B">Barbados</option>
<option value="C">Canada</option>
</select>
```

So whenselected, the input box shows "A", "B" and or "C"
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct .js and .css files.

This works for me:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.1/chosen.css">
</head>

<body>

 <select multiple style="width: 500px;">
  <option value="A">America</option>
  <option value="B">Barbados</option>
  <option value="C">Canada</option>
 </select>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.1/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('select').chosen();
  });
 </script>

</body>
```

In this example are used the external resources from [cdnjs.cloudflare.com](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com):

[3.1.0/jquery.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js)

[1.6.1/chosen.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.1/chosen.css)

[1.6.1/chosen.jquery.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.1/chosen.jquery.min.js)